# How can I display a variable inside some html code using the echo in php

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo 'How can I display a variable  inside some html code using the echo in php?';
?>
```

Comment: `<html><?= $username; ?></html>`

Comment: Your code will already do what you want. Just insert the variable inside the string, using double quotes instead of single: `echo "How can I display a variable  inside some html code using the echo in php? Like this: $username";`

Comment: why you give your negative opinion ? if you smart then avoid answer but every one have chance to learn.

Comment: please respect beginner. in your life you already facing this issue.

Comment: @HussyBorad who you're ranting with?!

Comment: @ Alan Machado  ranting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo 'How can I display a variable '.$username.' inside some html code using the echo in php?';
?>
<i><?php echo $username; ?></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write php code inside html by using php tags like

```
<p class='test'><?php echo "test php" ?></p>
```